# count number of variables selected in dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I could not find any example that suite my problem. I would like to count selected variables from drop down menu using javascript.

My biggest concern is, these drop down menu values are dynamically retrieved from db.The drop down menu is generated multiple times depending on number of student displayed in the form.

This is the codes for drop down menu of examiner name:

```
<select id="examinerID" name="examinerID">
<option selected disabled>Examiners Name</option>
<%
   try{
   //connection
   String query1="select lecturerID, lecturerFullname from lecturer ";
   while(rs1.next())
{
%>

   <option value="<%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %>"><%=rs1.getString("lecturerFullname") %></option>

    //close connection and exception
 %> 
</select>
```

This is how it actually looks like:

[image]

Below the form, I would like to add a list of the examiner (also retrieve from db) and I would like to count how many times an examiner has been selected.

Assume these are the value in drop down menu (to make it easy to understand):

```
<select id="examinerID" name="examinerID">
<option selected disabled>Examiners Name</option>
<option>Mark</option>
<option>Adam</option>
<option>Lucy</option>
<option>John</option></select>
```

Expected outcome of counting the selected examiner:

```
Mark: 2 //assuming Mark has been selected twice
Adam: 1
Lucy: 1
John: 0 //assuming John is not selected to be an examiner
```

Comment: Your first problem is that your code is generating invalid HTML. Element `id` values **must be unique**. If I'm reading your question right, you end up with multiple `select` elements with the `id` `examinerID`. So that's the first thing to fix.

Comment: How should i correct it?

Comment: @ Mong2203: By not outputting duplicate ID values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Id to class as you are creating multiple instance of select.
For eg:

HTML:-

```
<select class="examinerID" name="examinerID">
     <option selected disabled value="">Examiners Name</option>
     <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
     <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
     <option value="Lucy">Lucy</option>
     <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
<select class="examinerID" name="examinerID">
     <option selected disabled value="">Examiners Name</option>
     <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
     <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
     <option value="Lucy">Lucy</option>
     <option value="John">John</option>    </select>
<select class="examinerID" name="examinerID">
     <option selected disabled value="">Examiners Name</option>
     <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
     <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
     <option value="Lucy">Lucy</option>
     <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
<select class="examinerID" name="examinerID">
     <option selected disabled value="">Examiners Name</option>
     <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
     <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
     <option value="Lucy">Lucy</option>
     <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
```

JS:-

```
var count = {};
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[name=examinerID]");
for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++){
    selects[i].addEventListener("change",function(event){
    count = {};
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(select, index) {
        var selectedValue = select.value;
        if(selectedValue != "")
            count[selectedValue] = (count[selectedValue])?count[selectedValue]+1:1;
    });
    console.log(count)
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but how can i display the count for each name?

Comment: `console.log ` check console

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is this suppose to be written like this: ` count[selectedValue] = (count[selectedValue])?                      count[selectedValue]+1:1;` with long spaces

Comment: 2. Is it like this : Mark: <script>console.log(count)</script>

Comment: 1. Nop. Its the ternary or Conditional operator. No need for that long space.     
count[selectedValue] = (count[selectedValue])?count[selectedValue]+1:1;

2. Its part of JS itself. I have made an edit to the answer, please check above answer.

Comment: The JS you gave was to count the variables but how can I see the count value once I select the name?

Comment: copy and paste the above JS, after changing or selecting the value from drop down, press F12 to open developer tool, there you can see the output in 'console' tab.

Comment: The console returns an error  `hitcounter.jsp:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` which is this line `$(".examinerID").on("change",function(){`

Comment: $ is for jQuery. wait. i will change the above code to javascript only

Comment: Okay :) and how about displaying it in the HTML/JSP page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113837/discussion-between-sabith-and-mong2203).

Comment: chnage HTML part as well

Answer (score 1):

Re your HTML:

```
<select id="examinerID" name="examinerID" onchange="checkLecturer()">
```

First, remove that `id` value. If you're outputting that in a loop (as your screenshot suggests), you're creating an invalid document, as `id` values **must** be unique.

If your goal is to get the value of the `select` that changed, pass `this` into your `checkLecturer` function:

```
<select name="examinerID" onchange="checkLecturer(this)">
<!-- Here ----------------------------------------^^^^ -->
```

...and then in `checkLecturer`, the first argument will be a reference to the `select` element:

```
function checkLecturer(select) {
    // Use select.value or select.selectedIndex
}
```

If your goal is to access the values of **all** of the `select` boxes, you can find them with `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[name=examinerID]");
```

That will give you a `NodeList`, with a `length` telling you how many were found. You can access each one as though the `NodeList` were an array. So for instance, this will show the current value of each of them:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[name=examinerID]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(select, index) {
    console.log("#" + index + ": " + select.value);
});
```

*(More on that odd-looking use of `forEach` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) on looping through arrays and array-like things such as `NodeList`s.)*